# asp.net post request form empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm using angularJS + asp.net for post request but the Request.Form is always empty. Here is my code

Index.cshtml

```
<div ng-app="phone" ng-controller="phoneCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="phoneNumber">
    <button ng-click="sendSMS()"> Submit </button>
    <br>
    {{response}}
    {{error}}
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('phone', []);
        app.controller('phoneCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.sendSMS = function () {
                var params = {
                    phone : $scope.phoneNumber
                };

                var config = {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
                    }
                };

                $http.post('Home/sendSMS',params , config)
                .then(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.response = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.error = data;
                });
            };
        });
    </script>
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SendSMS()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The form has " + Request.Form);
    return Content("Received");
}
```

The Request.Form is always empty but I can see a phone entry in the request body of the post request so I'm wondering if I'm extracting the data wrong in .net

Comment: have you tried a post with post man or something? also in your controller, try `SendSMS(string phone)` and  `SendSMS([FromBody]string phone)`, and check if you get the value of the phone

Comment: @NevilleNazerane tried adding the parameters in SendSMS, get this error "UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE - The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method."

Comment: yes if you add `[FormBody]` would get that error unless you had sent in the exact format it was expecting (json). In which case we know that isn't the type being sent

Comment: any reason why you want to use Request.Form? or you just need the data?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I just need the phone data by post, the link georgeawg added solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to change `Content-Type` to Json.

```
            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;'
                }
            };
```

Comment: I get an exception 'Request.Form' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: this is the exact header that works with `[FromBody]`. Comment out your `Request.Form` and try the `[FromBody]` again with this js

Comment: @NevilleNazerane if I use application/json the value of phone is null and there is no data in the request body, so the data isn't actually populated

Comment: well when you use json the controller would expect a json object. Since you are passing an object in js, you need to look for an object in c#. alternatively you can try simply passing `phone` in js instead of the whole object